# Templated way to match std::variant index to type at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++20

Given a `std::variant` and an index referring to one of the `variant`'s types, I'm trying to get that type's data from a storage class and store it in an instance of the `variant`. Further, I'm trying to do this with a `vector` of indices, pushing into a `vector` of `variant`s:

```
using ComponentVariant = std::variant<Interaction, Position>;

void addComponentsToVector(Registry& registry, int entity,
                           const std::vector<uint8_t>& componentIndices,
                           std::vector<ComponentVariant>& componentVec)
{
    for (uint8_t componentIndex : componentIndices) {
        switch (componentIndex) {
            // Note that this matches the types in the variant
            case 0:
                componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<Interaction>(entity));
                break;
            case 1:
                componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<Position>(entity));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to generate the `switch` logic using templates, so I don't have to maintain it by hand, ie if I add a type to the `variant`, the function will handle it with no extra work.

If background helps, I'm putting the components into a `vector` of `variant`s so that I can run them through a struct serialization library and ship them across the network.

Comment: Why are keeping a separate record of active member of `stf::variant`? `std::variant` does keep track of its state: the duplication is not needed. If the external record doesn't match the actual active member, `std::varaint` will `throw`. You should instead use `std::holds_alternative` or `std::get_if`. But the prefered method is `std::visit` and pattern matching with `if constexpr`.

Comment: The separate record is needed because the variant isn't being used as the data store, it's only used as an intermediary for serialization. The vector of integers tells me which types I need to retrieve from the storage, then I pack those types into the vector of variants for serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't hard.

The trick is to make a `variant` of integral constants, whose value corresponds to the index.

This amusingly is stored as an integer at runtime.

We can then get the `variant` with the N'th engaged using a simple jump table, and hope the compiler optimizes it away.

Once we can do this, `std::visit` on the `variant` of constants gives us the runtime value as a compile time value:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index_v{};

template<std::size_t...Is>
using indexes_t=std::variant<index_t<Is>...>;
```

Now, we just need to make the indexes from a runtime value:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr indexes_t<Is...> get_index(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t I){
  constexpr indexes_t<Is...> retvals[]={
    index_v<Is>...
  };
  return retvals[I];
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_index(std::size_t I){
  return get_index(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, I);
}
```

We can now do `get_index<2>(0)` and get a runtime `variant` whose type is `index_t<0>`.

We can `std::visit` to extract the compile time value from the runtime `variant`:

```
int main() {
  auto r = std::visit( [](auto I){
    return sizeof(char[I+1]); // +1 is needed, as arrays of size 0 are illegal
  }, get_index<3>(1));
  std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Here `I` is a runtime constant.  All 0 through 2 versions of the template are created, but only the 1 is run.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/WoYjdoxb1).

Applies to your problem:

```
switch (componentIndex) {
  // Note that this matches the types in the variant
  case 0:
    componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<Interaction>(entity));
    break;
  case 1:
    componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<Position>(entity));
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

we do:

```
auto idx = get_index<2>(componentIndex);
std::visit( [&](auto I) {
  // here, I is 0 or 1 compile time constant.
  auto T = std::variant_alternative_t<I, ComponentVariant>;
  componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<T>(entity));
}, idx);
```

this automatically scales.

My system does NOT handle out-of-bounds values, however.  It will happily do undefined behavior in that case.

What it does is permit you to move a runtime index in a bounded range, and execute code where that runtime index is a compile time constant.  All of the compile time constant variations are *compiled*, but only the one matching your runtime index is executed.

And it does so without having to write your own bespoke code to handle each similar situation.

This technique can bypass the compile time index step -- you could instead pick a type from a list, instead of an integer from an index -- but I find that this is both less general and a bit trickier to keep track of.

The memory layout of the `index_t` is the most amusing part of this; at runtime, it is actually the value of the compile time constant the `index_t` holds.  The variant alternatives are all empty types, and the optimizing compiler can eliminate storage for them, leaving only runtime storage required for the index of the type stored.  And as the index of the type stored is equal to the compile time value of the type stored...

Why this works is that `std::visit` builds our jump table for us.  It builds each of the possible cases, and dispatches at runtime.  I find this to be a better idea than doing this manually.

Other useful functions along these lines include getting the `indexes` of a variant's alternative, getting a tuple of `index_t`s that let you access a tuple's members, converting `index_sequence`s into tuples of `index_t`s, etc.

Comment: `this isn't hard` ... "proceeds to create a constexpr variadic jump table of integral constant types".

Comment: I think I'm starting to see how this works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply it to my problem. Is the std::visit where I would get the data from my registry and push it into the vector? Or is there another step?

Comment: Nevermind, ecatmur's mp11 answer helped me figure it out. Using the tools from this answer, you can write an `addComponentsToVector` that looks just like the one in that answer.

Comment: Typo on argument order -> `std::visit(lambda, get_index<3>(1));`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html):

```cpp
void addComponentsToVector(Registry& registry, int entity,
                           const std::vector<uint8_t>& componentIndices,
                           std::vector<ComponentVariant>& componentVec)
{
    for (uint8_t componentIndex : componentIndices)
        boost::mp11::mp_with_index<boost::mp11::mp_size<ComponentVariant>>(
            componentIndex,
            [&](auto I) {
                using T = boost::mp11::mp_at_c<ComponentVariant, I>;
                ​componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<T>(entity));
            });
}
```

Comment: ctrl+f `mp_with_index`, there it is! +1.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I'm going to end up using mp11 instead of rolling my own helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pointer table to extract different types of objects from the `registry` based on different static index constants, and then use the runtime index to access the corresponding function for dispatch

```
void addComponentsToVector(Registry& registry, int entity,
                           const std::vector<uint8_t>& componentIndices,
                           std::vector<ComponentVariant>& componentVec)
{
  constexpr auto N = std::variant_size_v<ComponentVariant>;
  constexpr auto func_ptrs = []<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{
      +[](Registry& registry, int entity, 
          std::vector<ComponentVariant>& componentVec) {
        using T = std::variant_alternative_t<Is, ComponentVariant>;
        componentVec.emplace_back(registry.get<T>(entity));
      }...
    };
  }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

  for (uint8_t componentIndex : componentIndices)
    func_ptrs[componentIndex](registry, entity, componentVec);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a5bEz8McK)